# MPAndroidchart mChart set to null between onCreate and onResume

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I am trying to use MPAndroidChart to graph real-time data and am following the code examples [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a20EchSQgpw) and [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/RealtimeLineChartActivity.java).  I have had charts with static data working in the past.

Following the first example I initialize my globally declared mChart variable in the onCreate method.  However, when onResume is invoked, the mChart variable is set to NULL again and my addEntry() method fails due to a NULL exception.

What do I need to do to keep mChart from being set to NULL (other variables from the XML are initialized in onCreate and retain their values in onResume).

BTW, this app also has a BLE service running with source code that originated from the AndroidStudio BLE sample.

This is what mChart looks like a the end of onCreate (mDataField is included for comparison).

```
mChart = {LineChart@830034242904} "com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart{41e56d58 V.ED.... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0b0066 app:id/chart}"
mDataField = {TextView@830035362136} "android.widget.TextView{41f68158 V.ED.... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0b0068 app:id/data_value}"
```

mChart is declared as a class private variable:

```
private LineChart mChart;
```

My onCreate() method (according to the AndroidStudio debugger, mChart has a non-NULL value at the end of this method):

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gatt_services_characteristics);
        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        mDeviceName = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRAS_DEVICE_NAME);
        mDeviceAddress = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
        // Sets up UI references.
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.device_address)).setText(mDeviceAddress);
        mGattServicesList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.gatt_services_list);
        mGattServicesList.setOnChildClickListener(servicesListClickListner);
        mConnectionState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.connection_state);
        mDataField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data_value);
        getActionBar().setTitle(mDeviceName);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(this, BluetoothLeService.class);
        bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        // https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Getting-Started
        // in this example, a LineChart is initialized from xml
        LineChart mChart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
        // mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);
        // ---------------------------------------------------------
        // Set up chart formatting
        // ---------------------------------------------------------
        mChart.setDescription(new Description());
        mChart.setNoDataText("No Data Yet");
        // enable value highlighting
        mChart.setHighlightPerDragEnabled(true);
        mChart.setHighlightPerTapEnabled(true);
        mChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
        // enable scaling and dragging
        mChart.setDragEnabled(true);
        mChart.setScaleEnabled(true);
        mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
        // enable pinch zoom to avoid scaling x and y axis separately
        mChart.setPinchZoom(true);
        // alternative background color
        mChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);

        LineData data = new LineData();
        data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        // add data to line chart
        mChart.setData(data);

        // get legend object
        Legend l = mChart.getLegend();

        // customize legend
        l.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.LINE);
        l.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        XAxis x1 = mChart.getXAxis();
        x1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        x1.setDrawGridLines(false);
        x1.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);

        YAxis y1 = mChart.getAxisLeft();
        y1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        y1.setAxisMaxValue(120f);
        y1.setDrawGridLines(true);

        YAxis y12 = mChart.getAxisRight();
        y12.setEnabled(false);

        final Button emailButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_email);
        emailButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view){
                showEmailDialog();
            }
        } );
    }
```

And, my onResume.  According to the debugger, mChart is equal to NULL before the call to super.onResume() is executed.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver, makeGattUpdateIntentFilter());
    if (mBluetoothLeService != null) {
        final boolean result = mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
        Log.d(TAG, "Connect request result=" + result);
    }
    // Simulate real time data
    new Thread( new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
                // add 100 entries
                for(int i = 0; i<100; i++){
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            addEntry(); // Chart is notified of update in addEntry method
                        }
                    });
                    // pause between adds
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(600);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    }).start();

}
```

Finally, here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2013 The Android Open Source Project
     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at
          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/label_device_address"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
        <Space android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/device_address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200sp" />
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/label_state"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>
        <Space android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/connection_state"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/disconnected"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/label_data"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>
        <Space android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/data_value"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/no_data"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_email"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:text="@string/button_email_name"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/gatt_services_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining it as a local variable in `onCreate`

```
LineChart mChart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
```

Change that line to

```
mChart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
```

As `mChart` is defined as a field

Comment: Thanks!   That looks so obvious now.  (I'd upvote if I could).